# Java and Cucumber + Ivy

Tags: java, ant, cucumber, jruby, ivy

Does anyone have a good tutorial on Java + Cucumber integration?  I've begun using Ant + Ivy, but have unable to build project properly.  I've found the following [site](http://cuke4ninja.com/download.html), however after checking out their code the closest I've been able to come to building the project is the following error:

```
Buildfile: C:\workspace\cucumber-helloworld\build.xml
resolve:
[ivy:retrieve] :: Ivy 2.2.0 - 20100923230623 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:retrieve] :: loading settings :: file = C:\workspace\cucumber-helloworld\ivysettings.xml
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: cukes.info#java-example;working@SNKXW-SGENTRY
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve]  found cuke4duke#cuke4duke;0.4.4 in cukes
[ivy:retrieve]  found org.jruby#jruby-complete;1.5.1 in ibiblio
[ivy:retrieve]  found org.picocontainer#picocontainer;2.10.2 in ibiblio
[ivy:retrieve]  found junit#junit;4.8.1 in ibiblio
[ivy:retrieve] :: resolution report :: resolve 162ms :: artifacts dl 6ms
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      default     |   4   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   4   |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:retrieve] :: retrieving :: cukes.info#java-example
[ivy:retrieve]  confs: [default]
[ivy:retrieve]  0 artifacts copied, 4 already retrieved (0kB/6ms)
-define-paths:
-install-gems:
  [gem] JRuby limited openssl loaded. http://jruby.org/openssl
  [gem] gem install jruby-openssl for full support.
  [gem] System.java:-2:in `arraycopy': java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  [gem]     from DefaultResolver.java:111:in `makeTime'
  [gem]     from DefaultResolver.java:277:in `create'
  [gem]     from DefaultResolver.java:317:in `handleScalar'
  [gem]     from DefaultResolver.java:435:in `orgHandler'
  [gem]     from DefaultResolver.java:455:in `node_import'
  [gem]     from org/yecht/ruby/DefaultResolver$s_method_1_0$RUBYINVOKER$node_import.gen:65535:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:146:in `call'
  [gem]     from RubyLoadHandler.java:40:in `handle'
  [gem]     from Parser.java:300:in `addNode'
  [gem]     from DefaultYAMLParser.java:676:in `yyparse'
  [gem]     from Parser.java:290:in `yechtparse'
  [gem]     from Parser.java:284:in `parse'
  [gem]     from YParser.java:152:in `load'
  [gem]     from org/yecht/ruby/YParser$s_method_0_1$RUBYINVOKER$load.gen:65535:in `call'
  [gem]     from JavaMethod.java:630:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:186:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:172:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:172:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:199:in `executeBody'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:118:in `interpretWithJavaExceptions'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:110:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:172:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from FCallOneArgNode.java:36:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from EnsureNode.java:96:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from WhenOneArgNode.java:36:in `whenSlowTest'
  [gem]     from WhenOneArgNode.java:46:in `when'
  [gem]     from CaseNode.java:133:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:373:in `evalBlockBody'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:346:in `yield'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:303:in `yield'
  [gem]     from Block.java:194:in `yield'
  [gem]     from YieldNode.java:112:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:373:in `evalBlockBody'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:346:in `yield'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:303:in `yield'
  [gem]     from Block.java:194:in `yield'
  [gem]     from RubyKernel.java:1251:in `loop_1_9'
  [gem]     from org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$loop_1_9.gen:65535:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:299:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:117:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:132:in `callIter'
  [gem]     from FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:160:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:164:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:299:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:117:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:122:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:242:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:196:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:339:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:197:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:202:in `call'
  [gem]     from RubyClass.java:815:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:194:in `call'
  [gem]     from WrapperMethod.java:62:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:329:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:188:in `call'
  [gem]     from FCallTwoArgNode.java:38:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from LocalAsgnNode.java:123:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from EnsureNode.java:96:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:242:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:196:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:339:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:197:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:202:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallTwoArgBlockPassNode.java:62:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:283:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:212:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:359:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:237:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:252:in `callIter'
  [gem]     from CallThreeArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:262:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:204:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:349:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:228:in `call'
  [gem]     from FCallThreeArgNode.java:40:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:373:in `evalBlockBody'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:346:in `yield'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:303:in `yield'
  [gem]     from Block.java:194:in `yield'
  [gem]     from RubyIO.java:1104:in `open'
  [gem]     from RubyKernel.java:283:in `open'
  [gem]     from org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_2$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$open.gen:65535:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:198:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:339:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:197:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:212:in `callIter'
  [gem]     from FCallTwoArgBlockNode.java:34:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from IfNode.java:119:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from IfNode.java:119:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:221:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:188:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:329:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:188:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InstAsgnNode.java:95:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:199:in `executeBody'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:118:in `interpretWithJavaExceptions'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:110:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:242:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:196:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:339:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:197:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:202:in `call'
  [gem]     from RubyClass.java:815:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:194:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:329:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:188:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from DAsgnNode.java:110:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:373:in `evalBlockBody'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:346:in `yield'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:303:in `yield'
  [gem]     from Block.java:194:in `yield'
  [gem]     from RubyArray.java:1630:in `eachCommon'
  [gem]     from RubyArray.java:1637:in `each'
  [gem]     from org/jruby/RubyArray$i_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$each.gen:65535:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:299:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:117:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:122:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:221:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:188:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:329:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:188:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallTwoArgNode.java:59:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:199:in `executeBody'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:118:in `interpretWithJavaExceptions'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:110:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:373:in `evalBlockBody'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:346:in `yield'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:303:in `yield'
  [gem]     from Block.java:194:in `yield'
  [gem]     from RubyArray.java:1630:in `eachCommon'
  [gem]     from RubyArray.java:1637:in `each'
  [gem]     from org/jruby/RubyArray$i_method_0_0$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$each.gen:65535:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:299:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:117:in `callBlock'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:122:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:139:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:156:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:289:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:108:in `call'
  [gem]     from VCallNode.java:85:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from IfNode.java:119:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from IfNode.java:119:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:113:in `call'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:127:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:147:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:279:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:68:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallSpecialArgNode.java:73:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from CaseNode.java:138:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:172:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from FCallOneArgNode.java:36:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:199:in `executeBody'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:118:in `interpretWithJavaExceptions'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:110:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:172:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedMethod.java:180:in `call'
  [gem]     from DefaultMethod.java:172:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from CallOneArgNode.java:57:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:199:in `executeBody'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:118:in `interpretWithJavaExceptions'
  [gem]     from RescueNode.java:110:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BeginNode.java:83:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from RootNode.java:129:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from Ruby.java:2540:in `loadFile'
  [gem]     from ExternalScript.java:61:in `load'
  [gem]     from LoadService.java:255:in `load'
  [gem]     from RubyKernel.java:1010:in `loadCommon'
  [gem]     from RubyKernel.java:992:in `load'
  [gem]     from org/jruby/RubyKernel$s_method_0_1$RUBYFRAMEDINVOKER$load.gen:65535:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:190:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:186:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:309:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:148:in `call'
  [gem]     from FCallOneArgNode.java:36:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from NewlineNode.java:104:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from BlockNode.java:71:in `interpret'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:373:in `evalBlockBody'
  [gem]     from InterpretedBlock.java:327:in `yield'
  [gem]     from BlockBody.java:78:in `call'
  [gem]     from Block.java:89:in `call'
  [gem]     from RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
  [gem]     from ProcMethod.java:62:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:182:in `call'
  [gem]     from DynamicMethod.java:178:in `call'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:289:in `cacheAndCall'
  [gem]     from CachingCallSite.java:108:in `call'
  [gem]     from gem:1:in `__file__'
  [gem]     from gem:-1:in `load'
  [gem]     from Ruby.java:685:in `runScript'
  [gem]     from Ruby.java:568:in `runNormally'
  [gem]     from Ruby.java:414:in `runFromMain'
  [gem]     from Main.java:286:in `run'
  [gem]     from Main.java:128:in `run'
  [gem]     from Main.java:97:in `main'

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\cucumber-helloworld\build.xml:33: Failed to run gem with arguments: install cuke4duke --version 0.4.4 --source http://rubygems.org/
```

Total time: 10 seconds

Comment: Not an ivy issue. Retrieve task completed successfully. Looks like a Ruby gem failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the cuke4duke project is dead. Looking to replace this project with cucumber-jvm -- as seen [here.](http://groups.google.com/group/cukes/browse_thread/thread/299d94d38500e8c3)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered perhaps using [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) instead because it uses the same syntax (AFAICT) as Gherkin for describing behaviours and is native to Java. This should allow you avoid all the hassle with JRuby etc... unless of course you are writing JRuby code.

Comment: It will more than likely be the path I go down.  Right now I'm just researching options -- most of what people will find when they google cucumber and java (for now at least) will point them to cuke4duke which is dead.